# Is there any possibility to change programatically Square keys using Reader SDK?

Tags: android, square

We are using **Reader SDK** for payment processing in Square. In that keys assigned in `gradle.properties` file.

We have an android ordering application where multiple merchants access our application. We want to send payments to those merchants only.

We will ask Application Id and Password from merchant in our website and store details in our DB. Whenever merchant uses app we will get keys from service and need to assign

```
SQUARE_READER_SDK_APPLICATION_ID
```

and

```
SQUARE_READER_SDK_REPOSITORY_PASSWORD
```

Is there any possibility to change properties keys(`SQUARE_READER_SDK_APPLICATION_ID` , `SQUARE_READER_SDK_REPOSITORY_PASSWORD`) programatically with/without using “`gradle.properties`” file?

How can we update those keys programatically? Or any other possibility for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to ask for credentials from merchants (in fact, you shouldn't). What you would want to do is use Square's [OAuth](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/authz/oauth/build-with-the-api) API. This flow would enable you to provide a link to merchants with whatever permissions you desire. If the merchant chooses to give your application permission, you would receive a code, which you can exchange for an `OAuth access token`. You would use said access token to generate a [Mobile Authorization code](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/authz/mobile-authz/how-it-works), which is required to use ReaderSDK on each individual device. The `gradle.properties` then can keep using your (the developer's) application id and repository password without ever needing to change it.

The Mobile Authorization link I provided actually goes through the work flow of using an OAuth (instead of personal) access token.

Edit: I did notice you mentioned `ordering app`. Note that ReaderSDK is meant for in-person payments, not online payments. If you're wanting to take online payments with your Android application without using Square hardware, take a look at our [In-App Payments SDK](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/readersdk/what-it-does).

Comment: Thanks alot sjosey, We used Mobile Authorization API.